# Access public folder from image_tag in Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using `IMGkit` gem to generate and save file to the `public` folder in Rails root folder

I want to show that image in the `index` view.

I tried something like this

`<%= image_tag "#{Rails.public_path}/#{current_user.email}.png" %> <br/>`

But since it generates `localhost:3000/path/to/png-image` instead of `path/to/png-image` the image is not shown in the browser.

Any workaround? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Rails 3.2+, I would suggest you save images into your "app/assets/images" folder.

Then you can use something like this:

```
<%= image_tag "#{current_user.email}.png" %>
```

You can also use subdirectories:

```
<%= image_tag "generated_images/#{current_user.email}.png" %>
```

Learn more about the asset pipeline here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets

Comment: Let me try this @woodenfox

Comment: Thanks @woodenfox. It works!!!. But is there any way to have absolute URL to public folder?

Comment: You can think of /public as your root folder. As a result, the same code provided above should work.